# Tengo problemas para consultar registros en SQLAlchemy, le mando un print y me los muestra en consola, pero en el navegador no

Tags: fastapi

```
@router.get("/api/users",tags=["Visualizacipon de Usuarios"], status_code=200)
     async def get_users():
        with engine.connect() as con:
            usuarios = con.execute(users.select()).fetchall()
            con.commit()
            for i in usuarios:
                print(i)
            return usuarios
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour , también edita la pregunta y agrega todos los datos necesarios para evitar jugar a los detectives, las preguntas que tienen los datos necesarios, obtienen respuestas más rápidas en el mejor de los casos. Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.